# How to communicate with neo4j server from java app?

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm confused about how to connect with a remote neo4j server from java. Can I use the neo4j api directly, do I have to use the REST api??

Let's say my server is running in 270.270.270.270, I would want to:

```
cn = connect(270.270.270.270) 
results = cn.runSomeQuery //(with Cypher or... can I call a plugin or unmanaged extension?)  
return results
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, the dichotomy between the core Java API and the REST HTTP API is not always easy to grasp. Start maybe there: http://neo4j.com/developer/java/

> There are two ways of using Neo4j from the JVM. The standalone Neo4j
>   Server can be installed on any machine and then accessed via its HTTP
>   API.(...)
>
> But you can also run Neo4j embedded in your JVM process, much like
>   HSQL or Derby.

Unless you are 100% sure you will only need an embedded database, you can have a look at http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-java-rest-client-example.html for an example of using the REST API in Java.

```
final String txUri = SERVER_ROOT_URI + "transaction/commit";
WebResource resource = Client.create().resource( txUri );

String payload = "{\"statements\" : [ {\"statement\" : \"" +query + "\"} ]}";
ClientResponse response = resource
        .accept( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
        .type( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
        .entity( payload )
        .post( ClientResponse.class );
```

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this. I create a connection with the method i have created and then use another method like getHalt() to run a query. It is pretty simple i guess.

```
public class DbNeo {
    static Session ses;
    static StatementResult result;

    public static Session getSession() throws Exception{
        if (ses==null) {
            Driver driver=GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://270.270.270.270", AuthTokens.basic(username, password));
            ses=driver.session();
        }
        return ses;

    }

    public static String getHalt(String id) throws Exception{
        String halt = null;
        result=ses.run("MATCH (s:Halt) WHERE ID(s) ="+id+" RETURN s");
        return halt;
    }

}
```